# Cannot upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

We are trying to upgrade from Fabric Crashlytics SDK to Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
However, when trying to upgrade, we are unable to do so. The error is:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Crashlytics":
> In Podfile:
> Firebase/Crashlytics

> Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Crashlytics` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Additional details:

The current deployment target of our app is iOS 9, which we just recently upgraded.
We are also using Objective C as the main language for this project.

Current content of our podfile includes

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.0'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.0'
```

My questions are

1. Is it possible to still use Firebase/Crashlytics without upgrading our deployment target?
2. What is the minimum deployment target that can use the new Firebase/Crashlytics sdk?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify the contents of the Podfile. The description talks about 'Firebase/Crashlytics', but I don't see that in the contents posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites) the minimum project target for Firebase is iOS 8 or later.  I know that I have Crashlytics currently running in my own project which targets iOS 9, so your use case seems fine in that regard.  Which I think answers both of your two questions.

But, just looking at your podfile, I believe to reference Crashlytics you should had it looking more like this:

`pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'`

Mine looks like this.

`pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '6.32.2'`

No need for Fabric or Crashlytics on its own.  But it seems like the contents of your podfile, and the actual pod being found in your error message also don't match, so I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Hi and thank you for answering. The contents now of the podfile when I did the pod install are as follows:

`pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'`

We also have added
`pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`

So far, we're encountering issues on 'Firebase/Crashlytics' part when doing the pod install.


Additionally, on this page: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Crashlytics

It seems the minimum version needed for cocoapods is now 1.6.0

Comment: Yep that seems to be the case.  For my builds which get Crashlytics working on iOS 9 I have Cocoapods 1.9.1.  So perhaps you just need to update your Cocoapods?

Comment: Hi, updating our Cocoapods did the trick for me. Thank you so much!